# WAMP-like package for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cross-platform

I want to try what's hot with node.js, I am currently a user of WAMP on my local environment. Then I just push the changes to the centos production server with no sweat. Is there something like WAMP for node.js where I don't have to worry about mysql and others?

Answer (score 1):

The WAP part is the node itself, as it has its integrated web-server.

The M part depends on what DB do you want to use. I don't see any problems in installing two packages on your machine (Node and DB).